# Hide a TR who contains a TD who contains a specific input ID

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a `TR` line if it contains a textbox with a specific `id` in a TD

My HTML Code :

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="first_name">First Name</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="regular-text" value="My First Name" id="first_name" name="first_name" readonly=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="regular-text" value="My Last Name" id="last_name" name="last_name" readonly=""></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to hide the `tr` that contains the textbox with id "last_name".

I've tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
jQuery('tr:has(td:has(input[id="last_name"])').hide();
```

But this is working (but hide all of the tr):

```
jQuery('tr:has(td:has(input))').hide();
```

What have I missed?

--------EDIT---------------

Like  Arun P Johny said, I forgot a ')' like  :

```
jQuery('tr:has(td:has(input[id="last_name"]))').hide();
```

Comment: you missed a `)` in `jQuery('tr:has(td:has(input[id="last_name"]))').hide();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this -

```
$('#last_name').closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: Great, your solution is better than mine. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
jquery('#last_name').parent().parent().hide();
```